# Ubuntu 18.04 distribution on WSL fail to Set Default User via Config Command

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04

I am running Ubuntu18.04 on a windows 10 laptop, and I'd like to change the default user when starting a ubuntu bash window. The command I used is:

c:\ubuntu1804 config default-user my-ubuntu-username

The command runs successfully, but it did nothing.

I googled around and only found an unanswered question in a MS forum:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89081275-04e3-4b34-8714-baba9836ebc9/ubuntu-1804-distribution-on-wsl-fail-to-set-default-user-via-config-command?forum=win10itprogeneral

Does anyone have the same issue?  Is it a known bug?

Thanks

James

Answer (score 0):

The default user for ubuntu 18.04 takes effect after having restarted windows 10.